# How to align tab - materialize.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, materialize

I'm using `materialize.js` to generate some kind of Tabbar slider like you can see in my example below:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/css/materialize.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>


<ul style="position: fixed; top: 15%; height: 20%" class="tabs">
  <li class="tab">
    <a href="#a">LONG TEXT 123456789012345</a>
  </li>
  <li class="tab">
    <a class="active" href="#b">SHOULD BE CENTERED</a>
  </li>
  <li class="tab">
    <a href="#c">...</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<div id="a" style="position: fixed; top: 35%; width: 100%; height: 100%"> Test 1 </div>
<div id="b" style="position: fixed; top: 35%; width: 100%; height: 100%"> Test 2 </div>
<div id="c" style="position: fixed; top: 35%; width: 100%; height: 100%"> Test 3 </div>
```

---

But I got big trouble with **horizontal centering** the `second Tab` called "SHOULD BE CENTERED". I have no clue how I can move this TAB exactly to the middle of the screen because adding the attributes:

```
vertical-align: center
```

or

```
text-align: center
```

doesn't seems working at all.

EDIT: [image: img]
So I hope anyone is able to help me. Thanks a million in advance, Jane

Comment: Are you wanting horizontal centre? Vertical centre? Or both?

Comment: Then `text-align: center` works fine.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/406rfsvh/

Comment: _"I got big trouble with horizontal centering the second Tab (**"Test 2" / "#b"**)"_

Comment: @JaneDeverly - If it's fixed three li then you can try following CSS: 

.tabs li {
  width: 33%;
}

Comment: See, [everything can be improved with the addition of a free hand circle, though it should be red](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138031/is-there-a-joke-about-freehand-circles-that-im-oblivious-to).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As always : Flex is our lord and saviour :)

Make your `ul{ display : flex }` and then give each child a third of the width with `li {flex-basis : 33.33% }`

```css
ul.tabs {
    display : flex;
}

li.tab {
   flex-basis : 33.33%;
   border : blue dashed 1px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/css/materialize.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>


<ul style="position: fixed; top: 15%; height: 20%" class="tabs">
  <li class="tab">
    <a href="#a">LONG TEXT 123456789012345</a>
  </li>
  <li class="tab">
    <a class="active" href="#b">SHOULD BE CENTERED</a>
  </li>
  <li class="tab">
    <a href="#c">...</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<div id="a" style="position: fixed; top: 35%; width: 100%; height: 100%"> Test 1 </div>
<div id="b" style="position: fixed; top: 35%; width: 100%; height: 100%"> Test 2 </div>
<div id="c" style="position: fixed; top: 35%; width: 100%; height: 100%"> Test 3 </div>
```

Comment: `.tabs li { width: 33.3%; }` will do the same job. But thanks. Flex looks good `;)`